# Improve F# Debugging experience Visual Studio/Code

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, f#

The Visual Studio (and Code) Debugging experience is much worse for F# than C#. Most of the time it is impossible to inspect variables that are not in the very local context, especially when working with classes.
Often breakpoint are not binding even in basic line codes, and, even when they bind, sometimes they do not hit.

I am asking people to share knowledge on how to make that experience better, as for example  "tips and tricks" documents or links.

To begin with, I give my dime:

Sometimes watching into the "this" simbol while unwinding the call stack (when a breakpoint is hit) can give good information.

Comment: Personally I left step-through debugging far behind. I find debug tracing to be far, far superior. I suspect that people in F# community who would normally implement nice step-through debugging experience are of a similar persuasion, and so they don't.

Comment: You are not supposed to ask these kinds of questions on SO. The F# Slack is a much better place for a discussion about this.

Comment: @BentTranberg Based on  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic 
"software tools commonly used by programmers" I thought this could be an acceptable question. Would you please tell a little more on why this question is not suitable for stackoverflow (based on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic )?

Comment: I basically agree with the OP, FP'ers tend to not use debuggers as they tend to lend themselves more to an imperative mindset, order of execution often isnt obvious, but i can be frustruting...I can't offer much advice though.